# Storing search parameters

Tags: sql-server, xml, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, search

I'm currently building a website in .NET MVC 4, using Entity Framework to access SQL Server.

The website should have a complex search with multiple choices for the user, create a new search (free search), choose from the last 5 searches (history search), choose from stored search parameters.

What I'm having trouble with is the concept of saving the search parameters/sql string, because it's not sessional/cache based and should be stored somewhere (SQL Server / MongoDB / XML) I'm having the hard time in taking the most optimized path, if it's the SQL way then maybe create an entity that stores the search parameters as entities and afterward converting it into a SQL string for the search, or store it in XML and than serialize it with JSON.

Some fields of the search are not an exact db/entity match and requires summing/converting (like hours that would be calculated into certain time).

I'm more inclined to take out the best of Entity Framework abilities for the cause.

Would like to hear some expert thoughts if possible, Thank you.

Comment: How do you transfer the search parameters to the controller?

Comment: Still under theory, Probably by a submit button loaded with string variables that will be passed into a proper action.

Comment: If you use a parameter object you could serialize and store it.

Comment: Action method: `GetSelectedData(SearchParamDto paramDto)` => serialize/store the `paramDto` object. Later, the same method can be called with a deserialized object.

Comment: Mmm.. Where does the object being stored? I can't get the exact perspective from that example, Can you provide or link me to some more complex usage?

Comment: I'm still willing to learn more about this object, Can you give more details or link me to some guide about it?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is the "most optimized" path, but thought it seemed simple to implement:

```
//POCO class of item you want to search from database
public class SearchableItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

//MVC View Model for search page
public class SearchParamaters
{
    public int? MinAge { get; set; }
    public int? MaxAge { get; set; }
}

//Storable version for database
public class SavedSearchParameters : SearchParamters
{
    public int SavedSearchParametersId { get; set; }
}

//Use SearchParameters from MVC, or SavedSearchParamaters from EF
public IQueryable<SearchableItem> DoSearch(SearchParamaters sp)
{
    IQueryable<SearchableItem> query = db.SearchableItems;

    if (sp.MinAge.HasValue) query = query.Where(x => x.Age >= sp.MinAge.Value);
    if (sp.MaxAge.HasValue) query = query.Where(x => x.Age <= sp.MaxAge.Value);

    return query;
}
```

You could also serialize the `SearchParameters` class as XML/JSON and save it wherever, then deserialize it and pass it to the `DoSearch` method as normal, then you wouldn't have to change the DB schema every time you wanted to add search parameters

---

**EDIT: Full example using serialization**

\Domain\Person.cs

```
namespace YourApp.Domain
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

\Domain\SavedPersonSearch.cs

```
namespace YourApp.Domain
{
    //Entity object with serialized PersonSearchParameters
    public class SavedPersonSearch
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Parameters { get; set; }
    }
}
```

\Models\PersonSearchParameters.cs

```
namespace YourApp.Models
{
    //MVC View Model for search page
    public class PersonSearchParameters
    {
        public int? MinAge { get; set; }
        public int? MaxAge { get; set; }
    }
}
```

\Helpers\SearchProvider.cs

```
using YourApp.Domain;
using YourApp.Models;

namespace YourApp.Helpers
{
    public class SearchProvider
    {
        private YourAppDbContext _context;

        public SearchProvider(YourAppDbContext context)
        {
            //This example uses the DbContext directly
            //but you could use a Unit of Work, repository, or whatever
            //design pattern you've decided on
            _context = context;
        }

        public IQueryable<Person> SearchPersons(int savedPersonSearchId)
        {
            var savedSearch = _context.SavedPersonSearches.Find(savedPersonSearchId);

            //deserialize (example assumes Newtonsoft.Json)
            var searchParams = JsonConvert.Deserialize<PersonSearchParameters>(savedSearch.Parameters);

            return SearchPersons(searchParams);
        }

        public IQueryable<Person> SearchPersons(PersonSearchParameters sp)
        {
            IQueryable<Person> query = _context.Persons;

            if (sp.MinAge.HasValue) query = query.Where(x => x.Age >= sp.MinAge.Value);
            if (sp.MaxAge.HasValue) query = query.Where(x => x.Age <= sp.MaxAge.Value);

            return query;
        }

        public void SavePersonSearch(PersonSearchParameters sp, string name)
        {
            var savedSearch = new SavedPersonSearch { Name = name };
            savedSearch.Parameters = JsonConvert.Serialize(sp);

            _context.SavedPersonSearches.Add(savedSearch);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

\Controllers\PersonController.cs

```
namespace YourApp.Controllers
{
    public class PersonsController : Controller
    {
        private SearchProvider _provider;
        private YourAppDbContext _context;

        public PersonsController()
        {
            _context = new YourAppDbContext();
            _provider = new SearchProvider(_context);
        }

        //Manual search using form
        // GET: /Persons/Search?minAge=25&maxAge=30
        public ActionResult Search(PersonSearchParameters sp)
        {
            var results = _provider.SearchPersons(sp);
            return View("SearchResults", results);
        }

        //Saved search
        // GET: /Persons/SavedSearch/1
        public ActionResult SavedSearch(int id)
        {
            var results = _provider.SearchPersons(id);
            return View("SearchResults", results);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveMySearch(PersonSearchParameters sp, name)
        {
            _provider.SavePersonSearch(sp, name);

            //Show success
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks the closest to what i've been thinking about, Ill give it a try as soon as my DB creation stage will be done!

Comment: As for the View Model class to work with the POCO class, It's in a separate file from the POCO's class model? , Also about the storeable version for the db, Where should it be defined.. Just to clean the mess up a bit.

Comment: Also in the comment line :
//Use SearchParameters from MVC, or StoredSearchParamaters from EF//.  

You meant SavedSearchParameters as StoredSearchParamaters?

Comment: An Insert/Retrieve function to/from the SavedSearchParameters would be a great addition to your code.

Comment: @JBntis I will update my answer with solutions to your questions, but first do you need/want to have each search parameter as a separate field in the database for any reason (like to be able to find queries that specify a MinAge for example)? If not, I'll update my example to serialize instead

Comment: public IQueryable<Person> SearchPersons is built to search for particular model <Person>, If my search parameters are built from several models, How will I define it over multiple types and not just one?

Comment: the parameter set must be unified for all possible models parameters together.

Comment: @JBntis not sure I fully understand your question. Could you clarify what your search (input) type is, and what you want to return from the search/saved search?

Comment: Please see the graphic explanation:
http://oi43.tinypic.com/rkc555.jpg

There are parameters that could be selected from subgroups and sometimes subsubgroups , The parameters window navigation is made from a right pane menubar that will lead to each parameter category, when checking each parameter the parameter will be checked and move to the right pane accordion sidebar to show which parameters have been selected for search, Also there are ignore parameters as you can see in the example. Do you have clearer picture?

Comment: @JBntis really what I see from your graphic is how your are organizing your UI, not your view models or data layer. The only thing that I could suggest based on this, is it looks like you could use nullable booleans for your parameters in (null for no selection, true for checked, false for ignored).

Comment: You can take a look on how things are build in current mode which is not bad, The parameters are all built up in a table and can be played directly with SQL queries, However they are not filled into one compressed serialized row like in your example.

The code example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/KeKPz/2/

The HTML area is the search parameters model, One flat model that will be integrated with EF, The part of the JS is the Seed() method example of adding new saved parameters set from the user(As showen in UI in last post) , As you can see there are many tables that need to be united to work.

Comment: The thing is the flexibility in one flat model is that your can play with the SQL queries in every scenario with the required selection/joins and I'm not sure how to pull it up in the serialized example , With many tables that connected together dynamically and use flexibility of the SQL in the LINQ section. Do you have a clearer image now?

Comment: @JBntis I see your models and that is clearer so thank you, but I am still unsure what specifically you are asking / needing improvement. It's hard to decipher what parts of your comments are statements vs questions. Are you wanting to store the actual SQL Query That EF executes against the SQL server? If yes, my main question would be why, and see if there is a better solution to the reason you want to do that (like using SQL Server Profilder to examine the queries that are performed).

Comment: Also, look closely at my 2nd example in my answer, and you'll see that I don't store the `PersonSearchParameters` (which would be the equivalent of your `Search` class) directly in the database, I have a separate class/table called `SavedPersonSearch` in which I stored the serialized version of `PersonSearchParameters` with

Comment: Also, in your example, what is the type that your search is searching against? Is the purpose of all those tables to just store the possible values for each search parameter?

Comment: I appreciate the time you spend helping me out, Thank you.
The model was written in the meanwhile of trying to find out solution for the problem, Still haven't got to the part where I do dynamic loading of the parameters of which have already been saved.. But basicly all parameter will be stored in the Search and be taken can with SQL queries to load/save neccesery data.

The saved parameters will be insereted into a dynamic SQL query which will bring the specific search results later on on a grid.

Comment: Ill have more to update about difficulties in the next couple of days if you will be around!

Comment: Nice answer but how do you deal with old search critierias serialized and stored in db if you rename a property of the PersonSearchParameters Object ?

Comment: @toregua Yes, changing properties of serialized models can be a problem. Either A) Don't rename any properties, B) Be OK with old serialized data being invalid and getting dropped for renamed properties (this may be desirable if the meaning changes with the rename), C) Don't serialize the search parameters and save it to the database directly like in the first example, or D) Loop through the old records and update them (ouch). I would personally go with the "Just don't rename it" approach

Answer (score 1):

conver your parameters to Base64 string. It would help you to create any hard queries for example, http://www.jobs24.co.uk/SearchResults.aspx?query=djAuMXxQUzoxMHx2MC4x&params=cXVlcnlmaWx0ZXI6 decode base64 use this service http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/Base64Decode/default.aspx
you can also take a look on http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/ it may be give you an idea about worh with parameters in your project

Comment: The first example you gave me requires source analyzing and than I have no idea where to look up.
The second one refer to external storing which is not eligible for the project, Stored data should be intended for internal use only, Not to mention it's not available in my region:
"Amazon CloudSearch is currently available in the following Regions: US East (Northern Virginia), US West (Oregon), US West (N. California), EU (Ireland), and Asia Pacific (Singapore)."

Comment: regarding my first part of unsewer, additionaly you can try to use Lucene http://lucene.apache.org/core/ and for .Net http://lucenenet.apache.org/ with Lucene you can save   search parameters in base64 string and easy build any dynamic queries. you can find Lucine example in web very easy. Heppy coding :)

Comment: What's regarding your first part of answer??

Not sure if using Lucene won't create overkill for the project, I rather use pure entity framework object storing patterns inside the db without the need for apache, We use Lucene for some other project more for the search, less for the saving paramaters functions, but ill give it a look.

Comment: I am speaking about how you can store custom search parameters. with  Lucene you would get just additional flexibility and increasing your performance in search.

Comment: But if I want to use an object that will interface within the whole search module - entity framework based without the usage of external factors to store and than deserialize?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

Store the search parameters in json/xml and persist in DB table.
1. When you want to edit the search parameters (if you even allow this), use the json/xml to pre-fill the selected parameters so user can edit criteria.
2. When user wants to run search, take parameters from json and create/run the query.

OR

Store the search parameters in json/xml and persist in DB table and also create the sql query and store the sql string (after validating parameters)
1. When you want to edit the search parameters (if you even allow this), use the json/xml to pre-fill the selected parameters so user can edit criteria.
2. When user wants to run search, simply take the saved query string and execute it.